# Ansible assert module fails with "Invalid conditional detected: invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 1)"

Tags: ansible, assert, stat

I am working on a role that, at some point, creates a few new directories on an already existing path, of which the first is named "DB2_patching". Because multiple users need to be able to access these directories, I want to make sure that the directories "above" mine all have execute for others.

My plan was this:

1. split path with "DB2_patching"; hence I have the directories I need to check
2. split the shortened path again, on delimiter "/"
3. re-create the path with join and while doing that get the necessary information with stat
4. do a final assert to see if everything's alright

Well, this final assert is failing:

> "{"msg": "The conditional check 'result_join.results.0.stat.xoth'
> failed. The error was: Invalid conditional detected: invalid syntax
> (, line 1)"}"

The assert task looks like this and I am trying to loop a variable in which "item" is also variable. This is "result_join.results.{{ item }}.stat.xoth".

```
- name: check execute for others
  assert:
    that:
      result_join.results.{{ item }}.stat.xoth
    success_msg: "Directory has execute permission for others."
    fail_msg: "Directory doesn't have execute permission for others!"
  with_sequence: start=0 end={{ nr_entries }}
```

- I don't understand why the error occurs as I am able to extract values from result_join outside a loop; for example using ""{{ result_join.results.0.stat.path }}" with debug.

Seemingly, when I use "result_join.results.{{ item }}.stat.xoth" in a loop, something's messed up. How can I make this work?

Comment: Welcome to SO! See [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Update the question and minimize the problem to *'result_join.results.{{ item }}.stat.xoth'*. [Help others reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and remove irrelevant details.

Comment: I edited the post. I am sorry for not adhering to the policies in the first place. I hope this is more OK now.

Answer (score 1):

See [Referencing key:value dictionary variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#referencing-key-value-dictionary-variables). Reference the attribute

```yaml
    that:
      result_join.results[item].stat.xoth
```

For example

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    result_join:
      results:
        item1:
          stat:
            xoth: true
        item2:
          stat:
            xoth: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: result_join.results[item].stat.xoth
      loop:
        - item1
        - item2
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] ****
ok: [localhost] => (item=item1) => 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: item1
  result_join.results[item].stat.xoth: true
ok: [localhost] => (item=item2) => 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: item2
  result_join.results[item].stat.xoth: false
```

---

It's possible to display either a variable or a message. See [*debug*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/debug_module.html)

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: result_join.results[item].stat.xoth
      loop: [item1, item2]
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ result_join.results[item].stat.xoth }}"
      loop: [item1, item2]
```

Comment: Is it possible to use the path value in the assert messages? I am using xoth for evaluation, but would like to show a message like 'success_msg: "result_join.results[{{ item }}].stat.path has execute permission for others."' This isn't working.

Comment: Expand the whole expression. See the example appended to the answer.

Comment: Using "result_join.results[{{ item }}].stat.path" in success_msg yields: "msg": "result_join.results[0].stat.path"; using "{{ result_join.results[{{ item }}].stat.path }" yields {"msg": "template error while templating string: expected token ':', got '}'. String: {{ result_join.results[{{ item }}].stat.path }}"} Neither of them display the path for the item